# iOS: App icon appears on lock screen when beacon region detected, but not when circular region detected

Tags: ios, icons, cllocationmanager, lockscreen, clcircularregion

When monitoring for beacons, and a beacon is within range, the app icon is always displayed on the lock screen... But, if the app is within one of the monitored circular regions, it doesn't seem like the app icon is ever displayed.

I.e. CLCircularRegion monitoring doesn't seem to get the app icon on the lock screen for me

Code snippet:

```
CLLocationDistance monitorRadius = 2.0*1609.34; // 2 miles in meters;
CLCircularRegion *region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc]
                                  initWithCenter:_location.coordinate
                                  radius:monitorRadius
                                  identifier:_regionIdentifier];    
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
```

I've seen people SAY that registering for a circular region should work to get the app icon on the lock screen, given that an "entered" event is encountered, but I've seen a lot of people say it's not working...and I haven't seen the app icon on the lock screen yet myself for just a circular region.

Several responses on SO seem to be mixing up the two as well... (e.g. someone asks about region monitoring to get app on lock screen, and someone answers to use beacons).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to an Apple engineer and he stated that yes it should show the apps icon when within an CLCircularRegion. Unfortunately it is not working that way. Has anyone seen an app icon on the lock screen when monitoring a CLCircularRegion (using requestAlwaysAuthorization)?